Identify film about plane crash in Europe
I saw this movie way back in 2009. 
The setting has a plane crash that landed somewhere in Europe (not sure about the place). Some of the people there were friendly, and some were rude. There was a scene where a man fights with another, grabs a barbecue stick and tries to poke his eyes out with it. 
Anyway, later in the movie.. the group makes friends with someone who lives there. He has a big house that is located in a forest. A short walk from the house is a falls that goes through a water cave. Then near the end of the movie, the guy whom they thought was their friend tries to kill them all. 
I even remember that that friend had stapled the head of someone who was injured. So, that fake friend tried to kill them all, but they escaped by going over the falls and into the cave.
Has anyone seen this movie? Can someone tell me the title?

Welcome to the community. You may have more helpful information than you realize. If you know, please also describe the language, country and year of production, names of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Sounds like "Turistas" 
However, it was a bus crash and not a plane crash. 

"American college student Alex, his younger teenage sister Bea along with their close friend Amy are backpacking through Brazil. They meet up with similar companions: wild and crazy British mates Finn and Liam, together with Australian traveler Pru, on a cross country bus. They barely survive after it crashes off a cliff. Further mishaps occur due to becoming stranded on a beach by so-called "friendly locals", some of whom have deprived them of all their possessions! Searching for any sympathetic police, they meet familiar face Kiko, who offers to lead them to sanctuary that being a house deep in the jungle. But upon finally reaching this supposed safe haven Amy soon vanishes, and it is only then that they discover (way too late) that their "saviors" offering them shelter are operators of a black market specializing in running human organs, who are seeking unwilling foreign donors (foreign tourist) to benefit their unfortunate countrymen. In their captors' eyes, foreigners have come into Brazil, raping their precious lands of its rubber, sugar, gold--even using its people as throwaway sexual playthings. For this exploitation of their country, our backpackers are now set to go under the surgeon's scalpel, courtesy of the captors twisted ringleader Dr. Zamora, Brazil's answer to 'Dr. Giggles'."

One of the guys that is somewhat in on it gets his head stapled when he gets hurt and there is no doctor around at the large house in the woods. They also escape through the water caves at the end. 
Preview:



